# What options are there for customizing a scrollbar with dojo 1.8?

Tags: dojo

I'm currently working on a dojo application, but have a need for some customization of the scroll bars. Basically anything that mimics any one of the multiple jQuery based custom scrollbar plugins should be sufficient.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

there doesn't seem to be something out there yet mimicking the jquery scrollbar plugins, you can customize their look using css though !

Lucian

Source:

http://dojo-toolkit.33424.n3.nabble.com/Custom-Scrollbars-tp2776041.html

Comment: Yeah, I think that I might need to learn how those jQuery plugins work, and then just build my own dojo widget based on them. Definitely not the quick'n'easy solution I was looking for though.

Comment: Hope you are going to share it with others, i might a customizable scrollbar too in the near future...

Comment: Definitely, looks like something the community could use something like that. When I get around to writing that I'll post it up here.